# Unique div to delete - via live generated divs by jquery event

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jQuery triggering a div with live updates every 5 seconds. That works fine.  Sometimes those updates should be deleted immediately.

jQuery generates html like this:

```
<form>

<div id="live1">Aha I love you too
<input id="live1" type="hidden" value="1"><label id="livedel1">Delete 1</label>
</div>

<div id="live2">Thx man
<input id="live2" type="hidden" value="2"><label id="livedel2">Delete 2</label>
</div>

</form>
```

... and so on.

I need some help with HTML and jQuery how to send/separate specific id to jQuery so it can be deleted, since I'm kinda not into jQuery vals. Deletion is not a problem, just for jQuery to grab specific id.

Recommendations in HTML and jQuery are welcome and upper HTML can be changed to xy code no problem.

Comment: What are jQuery vals? What does "I upper HTML is about to change no problem" mean?

Comment: To delete the first element, something like: $('#live1').remove(); Or are you asking something else?

Comment: @ Juhana.. It means I can change html written in this question no problem to obey reccommended code.
@ Jordan.. I dont know how to separate number from a #live1, or #live2 and so on in jquery lets say...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have **multiple elements with the same id**.  This is not valid HTML and will cause you problems.

If you want to delete a div when the label is clicked, you could do this:

```
<form>

<div id="live1" class="live">Aha I love you too
<input id="livehidden1" type="hidden" value="1"><label id="livedel1">Delete 1</label>
</div>

<div id="live2" class="live">Thx man
<input id="livehidden2" type="hidden" value="2"><label id="livedel2">Delete 2</label>
</div>

</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.live').on('click', 'label', function() {
    $(this).closest('.live').remove();
});
```

The key is to fix your IDs to be valid, and add a class `live` to the parent elements.  Then you can use jQuery to search up the DOM and delete the parent `live` element. But, it is difficult from your question to tell if this is what you really want to do.

If you don't want to change your html, aside from the invalid IDs, you would need to do something like this:

```
$('form').on('click', 'label', function() {
    var num = $(this).attr('id').replace(/livedel/, '');
    $('#live'+num).remove();
});
```

This makes the assumption that your html may vary from item to item.  If your structure is always the same, you don't have to mess with IDs and can just use `.parent()`, although as I am suggesting, it is **not very robust**:

```
$('form').on('click', 'label', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Yeah, similar to my answer, but **better** since mine is a little bit deprecated :)

Comment: Just to grab specific id from that div mess :) And I think this will do :)

Comment: To grab the number from the ID, see my second example.  However, I would lean toward the first solution.  It requires less calculation, is more robust, and relies on classes and DOM structure, which is really the best way to approach things.

Comment: I tested it already and it does!! But this code works since it is jquery generated.. 

$('.live').live('click', 'label', function() {
    $(this).closest('.live').remove();
});

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat vague so I'm right now sort of assuming what you really want.

Based on your HTML (which can be improved), the following will remove the parent element (the div) whenever a click on a label (the "delete" label) is made.

```
$(body).on('click', 'label', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

This may be greatly improved by using a class for the delete-labels, delegate the click events to a container element instead of the body, etc.

With HTML like this (somewhat cleaner, IMHO):

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="message">
      Aha I love you too
      <label class="delete">Delete 1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="message">
      Thx man
      <label class="delete">Delete 2</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above JavaScript may be made slighly more fool proof:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.delete', function() {
    $(this).closest('.message').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you need to remove top level `<DIV>` of an update when `click` in invoked. You could do for example:

```
$('label.deleteTrigger').live(function(){
    $(this).parentUntil('div').remove();
});
```

This will go up the ancestors until it finds specified selected (`div` in my example) and remove it from `DOM`. You can read more about it [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/).

Also, you'll need to add `class` (`deleteTrigger`, again, in my example) into `label` so there is a way to identify elements which trigger deletion.

Comment: Please note that as of jQuery 1.7 `.live()` is deprecated. Use `.on()` instead.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that but still used to this way :) Thanks! ;)